# ¿Cuál es la forma más rápida de acceder a un objeto concreto dentro de un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, eficiencia

Supongamos el caso de que tenemos un array con una gran cantidad de objetos (>20.000) con este formato:

```
var arrayBusqueda = [
    {
         id:"valor de id",
         valor:"valor a acceder"
    },
    {
        id:"valor de id",
        valor:"valor a acceder"
    },
//...
]
```

Suponiendo que todos los IDs son valores únicos y queremos encontrar el objeto correspondiente a ese ID concreto, ¿cual sería el método más rápido y con menos consumo de memoria? Acorde a mi investigación creo que `find` es bastante rápido, pero, ¿es el método más rápido?

```
let valorBuscado = arrayBusqueda.find(x => x.id == "valor de id") //conseguimos el objeto a buscar.
```

Comment: Efectivamente, la función `find()` es la apropiada para lo que quieres. Esta itera el array hasta que encuentre un elemento que cumpla con la condición de búsqueda, no iterando el resto.

Comment: Puedes hacer tus propias pruebas de benchmarking, por ejemplo, aquí: http://jsbench.github.io/

Comment: Lo más rápido sería no usar un array, pero el coste de la transformación sólo tiene sentido si vas a cargar una vez ese array y consultarlo muchas veces. En ese caso yo transformaría el array a un Map, con lo que las consultas serías todas en un tiempo constante

Comment: @phpMyGuel y no hay ninguna aproximación que implique algoritmos escritos a mano como por ejemplo el algoritmo de búsqueda binaria o quizás con algoritmos recursivos? Voy a probar con la pagina que  kosmosan ha compartido y traeré algunos resultados con funciones escritas a mano y comparaciones.

Comment: @PabloLozano nada nada, eso es el problema, aunque el problema lo haya puesto de forma mas generalizada, quizás debería haber especificado que se trata de valores de datos recibidos desde una api de datos IOT recibidos en tiempo real, por tanto el array se actualizará cada X tiempo, tratar el array transformándolo es demasiado intensivo. Quizás lo más indicado sería (en mi caso concreto, para el problema formulado no se aplica) avisar a el programador de BackEnd para que reformule la respuesta recibida desde la API.

Comment: La buśqueda binaria funcionaría si el array está ordenado. Si consigues que el recurso te devuelva la lista ordenada por el valor del ID, podrías reducir el tiempo de búsqueda de n a log(n)

Comment: También, dependiendo el diseño, puedes considerar que el backend realice dicha búsqueda, si es que no es necesario tener >20.000 elementos cuando solo se necesita uno.

Comment: @Emeeus sí, estaría bien, seguramente acabemos haciendo eso, pero la pregunta realmente era más curiosidad a ver si realmente había algún algoritmo mejor.

Comment: La cuestión es el tiempo que se emplea en ordenar un arreglo para que sea óptimo para la búsqueda, este tiempo hay que sumarlo al tiempo total de cada búsqueda individual. En este caso no podemos guardar ese orden, habría que ordenarlo en cada consulta. Entonces en esta situación, con datos "desordenados", lo único que hay que tener en cuenta es no seguir iterando una vez que se encuentra el resultado. Dicho esto, en lineas generales siempre van a ser mas rápidas las funciones nativas que nuestra versión manual, aunque teóricamente hagan lo mismo. Conclusión: `.find` es lo mejor

Comment: Perfecto Emeeus, me parece una muy buena respuesta. Si quieres publicala como respuesta y la acepto de momento, y si en algún momento sale alguna mejor o algo nuevo, marcaré la nueva como mejor. Quien sabe, a lo mejor en ES12 o ES13 sale algo mejor.